# new Keyword and Method Hiding

Tags: c#, inheritance

The new Keyword is used to hide the base class implementation of the same. But I am not sure why the following code produces the output as Baseclass

```
class Baseclass
{ 
    public void fun()
    { 
        Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
    } 
} 
class Derived1: Baseclass
{ 
    new void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " "); 
    } 
} 
class Derived2: Derived1
{ 
    new void fun()
    { 
        Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
    }
}
class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(string[ ] args)
    { 
        Derived2 d = new Derived2(); 
        d.fun(); 
    } 
}
```

We are hiding the implementation of fun in derived2 but still Base class is called why so? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your methods have different visibility (public vs private)

Answer (score 22):

`Derived2.fun`is private (it is the default access modifier of the members of the type). It is not visible outside the class. Only visible `fun` method outside the class is `Baseclass.fun` and thus it is invoked.

You need to make your `Derived2.fun` visible outside the class to get the expected output. You can do it by either making it public/internal.

Comment: Great spot! You should also explain *why* `Derived2.fun` is private

Answer (score 6):

Generally, hiding in C# works like this: the "hider" (a method or field or whatever declared with the `new` keyword) takes over all "functionality" it can from whatever is being "hidden". For example:

```
class Baseclass
{ 
    public void fun()
    { 
        Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
    } 
} 
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{ 
    new public void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " "); 
    } 
}
```

Here, `fun` in `Derived1` hides `fun` in `Baseclass` completely, because they have exactly the same "functionality": they are both methods, and are both `public`, i.e. available from anywhere.

However, if the "hider" doesn't cover all of the "hidden" member's functionality, it will still be there, ready to do its job. Example:

```
class Baseclass
{ 
    public void fun()
    { 
        Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
    } 
} 
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{ 
    new public int fun;
}
```

Here, `Baseclass.fun` is a method, and `Derived1.fun` is a field.

You can access the "hiding" field in an assignment expression like this: `int a = new Derived1().fun;`. As it is hiding the base class method `fun`, you cannot access it (the method) this way: `System.Action a = new Derived1().fun;` fails.

But what happens if we do something to `fun` that an `int` field can't do? `new Derived1().fun();` will work, calling the `fun` in the base class!

This specific example is even mentioned on MSDN on the [new Modifier page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx):

> Generally, a constant, field, property, or type that is introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members that share its name. There are special cases. For example, if you declare a new field with name N to have a type that is not invocable, and a base type declares N to be a method, the new field does not hide the base declaration in invocation syntax.

Your case is very similar. The `fun` methods in your two derived classes are hiding just part of the original `fun` in the base class. If you call `fun` from inside `Derived1` or `Derived2`, you will end up with the "hider" version of `foo` of the respective class. However, when you call `foo` from outside your three classes, the `public` method of `Baseclass` is called, because its `public` functionality has not been hidden...

Comment: But why use the "new" keyword at all? It functions the same with or without it in my experiments. The only difference is a compiler warning.