# How is the new keyword used to hide a method?

Tags: c#

I have read an article regarding the `new` keyword. It says it is used to hide methods. This is example they give:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class SampleA
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sample A Test Method");
        }
    }

    class SampleB:SampleA
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sample B Test Method");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SampleA a = new SampleA();
            SampleB b = new SampleB();
            a.Show();
            b.Show();
            a = new SampleB();
            a.Show();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Sample A Test Method
>
> Sample B Test Method
>
> Sample A Test Method

So my question isn't the `new` keyword used to instantiated an object? and its used to allocate memory for new created objects? Then how can method hiding be done using it? And is above example correct?

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: The "new" word has several meanings in C#. One of which is to hide a base class method in a subclass.

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208180/new-keyword-and-method-hiding?rq=1

Comment: @JDE :here is link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/09/csharp-virtual-override-new-keywords-example.html

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati provided link itself explains the actual work of `new` keyword in method hiding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`new` is used for 3 different things. You could say there are 3 different keywords with the same name.

1. It's an operator, used to invoke constructors.  Example: `new object();`
2. It's a modifier, used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.  Example:

   ```
   class Base {
       public void MyMethod() {
           //Do stuff
       }
   }

   class Derived : Base {
       public new void MyMethod() {
           //Do other stuff
       }
   }
   ```
3. It's a generic type constraint, used to indicate that a generic type parameter has a parameterless constructor. Example:

   ```
   class MyGenericClass<T> : where T : new() { ... }
   ```

Source: [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx)

Comment: i understand what you want to say.but in example i posted in question there is no new keyword in show method of derived class.then how object of SampleB calling show() method of SampleA?

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati The `new` keyword is implied. It's not an error to omit it, but it's there even if you don't type it.

Comment: then in main method there are 2 objects of sampleB.first one is salling Show() of sampleB. and second one is calling Show() of SampleA.why?

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati The *compile-time type* of `a` is `SampleA`, because you declared it as `SampleA a = ...`. When you call `Show()`, it will call the method declared in `SampleA`. It will not look at the *runtime type* of `a`, because the method is not virtual. (The first time, the runtime type is `SampleA`, the 2nd time it's `SampleB`, but the compile-time type is always `SampleA`) The compile-time type of `b` is always `SampleB`, because you said `SampleB b = ...`

Comment: you make my confusion totally clear now..thanks a lot @Dennis

Comment: In my case the implied "new" keyword does give a warning suggesting to make it explicit. To make it use the derived class method in spite of casting to the base type, you need to use the "override" keyword instead.

Comment: should be `public new void MyMethod() {
        //Do other stuff
    }` I mean new should come before void.

Comment: @bayram Learned something new. Thnx.

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't the `new` keyword used to instantiated an object?

Yes it is. Among other things.

> then how can method hiding done using it?

The `new` keyword in the context of method and property definitions has another meaning than the `new` keyword used to instantiate objects. The `new` keyword in that context tells that there is a new start of the inheritance tree of that particular method or property. That's all.

Comment: Insteas of saying "start of the inheritance tree" I would just say that *it's re-using an identifier*, isn't it?

Comment: Well, yes. But it breaks the inheritance tree, which in my opinion was a key part in the misunderstanding of OP.

Answer (score 2):

> Then how can method hiding be done using it? And is above example
>   correct?

Programming language syntax, grammar and semantics are just an arbitrary set of conventions and specifications. That is, C# can invent one, two or dozen of usages of a given keyword like `new`.

When `new` is used during a class member declaration, it means that you're re-using an identifier:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    new public int Text { get; set; }
}
```

As you can check in above code sample, `B` also implements a `Text` property, but since derives from `A` which has also defined a `Text` property, there's a naming collision.

The so-called `new` keyword can be used to re-use `Text` identifier and being able to implement another property `Text` which may behave absolutely different than the one implemented in the base class. See that `Text` on `B` is of type `int`!

The most important point here is that re-using identifiers isn't the same as using polymorphism, where a class method or property override must match base class' member signature:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string Text 
    {
         get { return base.Text; }
         set { base.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Also, re-used identifiers are dangerous:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    new public int Text { get; set; }
}


B b = new B();
b.Text = 4;

// Upcast B to A
A a = b;
a.Text = "Bye bye";

Console.WriteLine(a.Text); // Output: Bye bye
Console.WriteLine(b.Text); // Output: 4
```

See the output of Text. Since re-using identifiers isn't *polymorphism*, and in above case both are completely different properties, there's an `A.Text` and `B.Text` that can be set separately.

Comment: "The most important point here is that re-using identifiers isn't the same as using polymorphism, where a class method or property override must match base class' member signature"

That was the key to me to understand why `new` keyword in this context is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class by using the same member name, and modify it with the **new** keyword. For example:

```
public class BaseC
{
    public static int x = 55;
    public static int y = 22;
}

public class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    // Hide field 'x'.
    new public static int x = 100;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Display the new value of x:
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        // Display the hidden value of x:
        Console.WriteLine(BaseC.x);

        // Display the unhidden member y:
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
/*
Output:
100
55
22
*/
```

You can read more in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)